# Subclassing window procedure of an ActiveX control in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, activex

I'm using a Flash ActiveX control in my application. I would like to disable its right click menu. As the control does not provide an API for this, I want to subclass the window procedure and intercept the WM_RBUTTONDOWN message. I successfuly did this under Qt, but I have no idea how can do it in C#.

In my C++/Qt implementation I used `SetWindowLong` to store the `this` pointer of the activex wrapper which in turn had a field that stored the oringal window proc. I set the window procedure to mine (again with `SetWindowLong`) and any messages that I don't want to process, I pass to the original WNDPROC with CallWindowProc.

How can I do this under .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this exactly the same way in C#. You need to use P/Invoke to call the unmanaged Windows API from managed code. There are lots of articles on the web that show how to use P/Invoke.

In fact you can do it in an even easier fashion using the `NativeWindow` class as explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815775#5). The code looks like this:

```
public class SubclassHWND : NativeWindow
{
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
      // Perform whatever custom processing you must have for this message
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(m.ToString());
      // forward message to base WndProc
      base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
}

SubclassHWND s = new SubclassHWND();
s.AssignHandle(theWindowHandle);
//Now s should be listening to the messages of the form.
```

Another way to use a delegate in place of a function pointer is: [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx)

Comment: Can I really pass a C# method to SetWindowLong?

Comment: Yes you can do so and it is routine to do so.

Comment: I've done a websearch myself and found that it's actually possible in an even easier way without P/Invoke - see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the meanwhile I figured out how to actually pass a C# method as a function pointer to winapi, I added it to your answer for future googlers (if you don't mind :)).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old one, I just came across this code from this link and it is VERY useful. Essentially, it subclasses the ActiveX control itself and disables right click at that point.

Via: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29102/How-To-Disable-FlashPlayer-AxShockwaveFlash-Right

```
public class IForcePlayer : AxShockwaveFlash
{
const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
}
```